# The un-googleable ruby's method method

Tags: ruby, methods

There is apparently a ruby method called **method** and I can't find any docs or examples on it so far. Could someone please post a few useful annotated examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best uses of the bound method object returned by `Object#method` is for blocks. The return result of that method can be converted to a block argument. Imagine you have:

```
class Converter
  def convert_item(item)
    item.transmorph
  end
end
```

Then you could do this

```
c = Converter.new
elements.map(&c.method(:convert_item))
```

or when you are within the convertor

```
elements.map(&method(:convert_item))
```

which IMO is more elegant than the explicit block creation syntax. It also supports `to_proc` so you can do this

```
some_object.callback = my_handler.method(:activate).to_proc
```

and then in `some_object` you can do

```
@callback.call(data)
```

Answer (score 6):

there is docs about that method in ruby api documentation

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method

there is also method_defined? which could be also useful if you need method it self

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-method_defined-3F

Answer (score 3):

I've mostly used it to look up source location of a specific method. (example run in irb on ruby-1.9.2-p290)

```
class Thing
  def foo
  end
end

Thing.new.method(:foo).source_location
=> ["(irb)", 2]

Thing.new.method(:foo).owner
=> Thing
```

Comment: For those using Ruby 1.8, you can do `owner`, but not `source_location`.

Comment: In other words, you should have done `Object.new.method(:method)` to look up the `method` method!

Comment: The problem with Object.new.method(:method) is that #method is a native method, returning nil for the message #source_location, hence the contrived example.

Answer (score 2):

`Object#method`, is this what you are looking for?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method

Answer (score 2):

It's part of Object and is documented here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method

The class `Method` is documented here, and gives some examples:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html